# SQL JOIN to get distinct column from second table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a table `Mark` with `id` and `name` fields and second table with `mark_id` and two extra columns I'm interested in. I want to get all records from `Mark` table + priority for that mark and `created_at`. There might be several `created_at` values but I do not care much about them, I need just need one (first, whatever).

I tried this query which gives me too much records, 5 instead of 3 I expect.

```
SELECT 
    marks.*, 
    markings.created_at, 
    markings.created_at AS updated_at,
    markings.priority 
FROM `marks` 
JOIN markings 
    ON marks.id = markings.tag_id
WHERE (created_at > '2011-11-06 12:05:01') 
    AND (priority = 1) 
ORDER BY created_at;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    marks.*, 
    MIN(markings.created_at) as created_at, 
    MIN(markings.created_at) AS updated_at,
    markings.priority 
FROM `marks` 
JOIN markings 
    ON marks.id = markings.tag_id
WHERE (created_at > '2011-11-06 12:05:01') 
    AND (priority = 1) 
GROUP BY marks.col1, marks.col2, ... marks.coln, markings.priority
ORDER BY created_at;
```

where `marks.col1, marks.col2, ... marks.coln` would be `marks.id, marks.name` in your case if you don't have more columns you don't tell us about.

Answer (score 1):

This query group the result  by markings and id, should be what you want :

```
   SELECT 
    marks.id, 
    MAX(markings.created_at), 
    MAX(markings.created_at) AS updated_at,
    markings.priority 
FROM `marks` 
JOIN markings 
    ON marks.id = markings.tag_id
WHERE (created_at > '2011-11-06 12:05:01') 
    AND (priority = 1) 
GROUP BY marks.id,markings.priority
ORDER BY updated_at;
```

Comment: Column 'marks.name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Column "marks.created_at" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.